# Angular 2: sharing data across different routes

Tags: javascript, angular

I have searched for similar questions in SO and I have not found any that addresses my specific case. There are many techniques to share data between angular components, and I have read this article about component communication: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

However none of the techniques described there work for me, because my components are on different routes. The article describes mostly parent-child component communication, and some cases may work for sibling components as long as they are both loaded at the same time.

My case is very similar to the Angular 2 Heroes tutorial: I have a route that displays a table with a list of customers (instead of heroes). When the user clicks on a specific customer, I trigger a route change to display a form with the data for the selected customer (instead of hero).

The heroes tutorial performs a service invocation to retrieve the selected hero data, but I want to avoid a useless additional AJAX call, given that those data are already in memory. I just want to pass the selected customer data to the customer form component so it is immediately displayed.

I am thinking of a "global session" service where I could store and retrieve any object I want, but I am not sure this is a good idea. Are there other more adequate approaches?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use service that is provided by main application file and then inject it whenever you want to get/set data that will be available in whole app

main.app.ts

```
@Component({
...
  providers:[yourDataService]
...
})
```

other components

```
import {yourDataService} from '...';

@Component({
...
providers:[]// we must use provider from main file
...
})
export class someComponent{

  contructor(private myData:yourDataService){}

}
```

it is important to use provider from main app file because if you provide service in each component you will have another instances of your service and of course different data in each service

you can also use [observables](http://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html) to be notified when some data has changed

for more info look at [hierarchical injections](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html) or [tree injector](http://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/di/angular2/the_injector_tree.html)

Comment: This looks similar to my "global session" service. What would the API of "yourDataService" look like? Something like setCustomer() / getCustomer()?

Comment: @Luis Crespo yes exactly, this is the simplest and the best approach I think

Comment: Thank you. Because this is pretty much what I was thinking about, I will wait a bit more to see if someone comes up with some alternate approach.

It seems strange to me having to develop this kind of service at the application level for such a common scenario. Maybe Angular 2 already provides some simpler mechanism.

Comment: About the observables edit: given that my "customer details" component has not yet loaded when the user selects a specific customer from the customer list, it will have not registered as a listener when the "customer selected" event is triggered. Would my component still be notified in such scenario?

Comment: Luis Crespo,the service is a valid aproach..the only difference is that your service is statefull and a singleton..
Image a world where your service would query a database or a webservice... your component should call a service to query its data.
. you could change the statefullness by creating a cache object, (which will be initiated as @neutronet suggests for the service and injected into the CustomerService)
so at least your service would be stateless and you wont have to initiate it in the main.app.ts.

Comment: @OliverRenner I guess it makes sense for the service to cache data, although it has its drawbacks: the service has less awareness to when is it OK to cache and when it is not.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the is is what you're after but if you need to share data across sibling routes you could try this.

Create a module Import and Declare the service in the module

```
import { MyService } from './my.service’;

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    MyService
  ]
  …
})
```

Declaring the the service in the module route means we can then pass the service by reference to the child routes. Do not use the service in the parent component

In the child route components, import the service

```
import { MyService } from '../my.service’;
```

In each component where the service should be used, do not add the service to the components metadata because we’ve already added it to the module definition. Add the service to the component constructor

```
export class MyChildRouteComponent implements OnInit {  
...
 constructor(
    private _myService: MyService,
    private _router: Router
  ) { }
 ...
}
```

If you then set a service property in one child route component, you will then be able to get it from a sibling child component.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am doing :-)

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about **NgRx** solution inspired by Redux? You can read more there - https://github.com/ngrx/store

You will have a single application store, which can be subscribed in the proper components. So - you could just dispatch an event before route changed. This soulution use only reducers, so in different ways than using store, your data would be immutable - this is the next advantage.

Comment: Thank you, I have quickly checked it and it seems it's about adopting Redux philosophy in Angular. I will carefully read it...

Comment: Very interesting, but this looks like an "all or nothing" approach, i.e., to be used across all my application, not only to solve this specific problem. I am a big fan of Redux so I will consider it for a future project.